# Drop identity property

Tags: sql-server

When removing the identity property from a column via the GUI design table option I believe the table (and if the column is a key field; any associated non-clustered indexes) are recreated.

Does anyone know of a way to drop the identity property from a column without causing this overhead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do it in TSQL without dropping the column.  Maybe add a new column without the IDENTITY property, copy the data, drop the old column?